# Is it legal to pay for online advice? How would it be taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Here on stack exchange we getting known about intresting topic and can pay back with vote.

- Is it legal to pay with money in general (not in Stack exchange)?
- How it would be accounted by IRS in a context of taxing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely legal and will be accounted by the IRS as earned income.

Comment: It would be nice to have more extended answer with references to official documents and/or existed samples

Comment: @aleks.n.fedorov In the United States, official documents and references are for limitations, things forbidden. Whatever is not explicitly forbidden - is generally allowed.